# MySQL INSERT INTO: Multiple lines with one query

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a table DateID just with two fields:

id (integer), date(datetime)

```
id          date
1           2013-06-27 12:00:00
2           2013-06-27 12:00:00
```

I need to populate the table with **2 new lines with just one query**. Is it possible?

Data:

```
id =1 date= 2013-06-27 12:00:00;
id =1 date= 2014-06-27 12:00:00;

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO DateID(id,) 
values ('1','20141127120000,20161027120000')");//is this possible?
```

Comment: oh and use mysqli just to be future proof http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php :)

Comment: Be aware that the `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated and support for them will be removed. For new code use `mysqli` or `PDO`. The suggested queries given will still be valid.

Comment: or use a [prepared statement](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and just repeat the same query with new parameters.

Comment: mysql bad spam spam spam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO DateID(id,date) 
values (1,'20141127120000'),
       (2,'20161027120000')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this probably?

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO DateID(id, date) VALUES ('1','20141127120000'), ('2', '20161027120000')");
```